# How to unmount partition in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have one pod and one partion in it

```
kubectl exec pod-t -- lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
`-sda10   8:10        28G  0 part /etc/hosts
sr0      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
rbd5    252:80   0    15G  0 disk /usr/share/nginx/html
```

When i want umount it i see

> must be superuser to unmount

```
#kubectl exec pod-t -- umount /dev/rbd5
umount: /usr/share/nginx/html: must be superuser to unmount
command terminated with exit code 32
```

The pod was created by this template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-t
  namespace: default
  labels:
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginxqw
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - name: content-data
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  volumes:
  - name: content-data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
     claimName: pvc-t
```

I think the pod does not have root priviledge.
How can i solve it?

Comment: Why do you want to `unmount` it? Can you share the manifest used to deploy that pod?

Comment: I want to remount it to update some changes

Comment: That's not a common practice with kubernetes. I suggest you build a docker image with your "code/website" in it, push it to your registry and use a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) to rollout the changes in a safe manner.

Comment: no it is not common rollback.I know i can use deployment. but i should remount it.
I know it is possible to unmount it. but the question is how?

Comment: What type of "changes" you want to do? Can you edit your question explaining your use case?

Comment: i want to take snapshot by ceph and rollback it. and i want to do it just by ceph

Comment: Hi, can you try with `sudo umount /dev/rbd5` ?

Comment: the sudo not work in container

Comment: you are exposing containerPort: 80 which mean you have root privileged

Comment: but in container i do not have right privileged

Comment: you can check the permission of the file system `ls -la`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191966/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-yasin-lachini).

Comment: #kubectl exec nginx -- ls -la –


ls: cannot access ''$'\342\200\223': No such file or directory
command terminated with exit code 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a privileged flag on the SecurityContext of the container spec.

I use this template

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  containers:
    - name: hello-world-container
      # The container definition
      # ...
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
```

Comment: So did it help ? were you able to unmount the device ?

Comment: So there are two thing , you need to be root as well as have the privileged